# blueimp jquery file upload user upload directory with custom username not sessionid

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I am looking for a way to get the blueimp jquery file upload plugin, [available here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), to use a custom user name like "john.doe" (I have implemented [this authentication plugin](https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login)) instead of the session id
(I assume it is the session ID) like hhhbu7p69sl6ocf07757h77097.

I activated the option user_dirs in the UploadHandler.php to have user directories. But I need to have it relative to the username so that the path would be relevant over multiple user login sessions.

Thank you in advance for any insight or hint.
Please ask anything and excuse me if I omitted something important as this is my first post to stackoverflow.

Comment: Basically instead of uploading to somthing like: 
/var/www/html/server/php/files/hhhbu7p69sl6ocf07757h77097
I need to upload to something like:
/var/www/html/server/php/files/jane.doe

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it myself but... I did it
In the file UploadHandler.php there is this class and it has this function which I modified it to:

```
protected function get_user_id() {
    @session_start();

    foreach( $_SESSION as $key=>$user ) {
            $username = $user;
    }
    return $username;

    #return session_id();
}
```

That's it! Now it creates directories with the user name.